# How to get the currently clicked radio button

Tags: python

I'm doing a project in Python for college from which I have to make a User Login/Reg system which will contain both Admin and Standard user sessions, for it's simplicity, the user can select it's user permission on registration in the form of radio buttons in a signup.html file.

```
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" maxlength="45" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" maxlength="45" placeholder="Password" required>

<input type="radio" name="userRole" value="standard">Standard
<input type="radio" name="userRole" value="admin">Admin
    <br><br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button>
  </form>
```

In my python code, I'm able to get the username and password, but I'm unsure as to how I'd get the value of the currently clicked button.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']
        _access = request.form[ .... ]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you try `request.POST['userRole']`?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro That didn't work, but I figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was simple, it was exactly the same as the previous requests from the forms:

```
_access = request.form['userRole']
```